# Vagrant NS_ERROR_FAILURE, component machine, interface imachine

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 17.10, a fresh install of vagrant, and a fresh install of virtualbox. For some reason I keep getting this error at boot of the virtual machine. There are no logs to go from because the virtual machine does not get created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the version of Vagrant and Ubuntu, just stick to LTS releases and you'll be fine.